# Scala alternative to an infinite loop

Tags: scala

Is there any more functional alternative in Scala for an infinite loop?

```
while(true) {
  if (condition) {
    // Do something
  } else {
    Thread.sleep(interval);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing that you can do is using higher-order functions like `Stream.continually` and pair it up with a `for` comprehension:

```
import scala.util.Random
import scala.collection.immutable.Stream.continually

def rollTheDice: Int = Random.nextInt(6) + 1

for (n <- continually(rollTheDice)) {
  println(s"the dice rolled $n")
}
```

This example itself is not purely functional due to the non-referentially transparent `nextInt` method, but it's a possible construct that may help you think about function composition rather then using side effects.

#### EDIT (2020-12-24)

As correctly point out in a recent comment, "[a]s of 2.13, Stream is deprecated. But the same method does exist in LazyList(import scala.collection.immutable.LazyList.continually)".

The following will work from 2.13 onward:

```
import scala.util.Random
import scala.collection.immutable.LazyList.continually

def rollTheDice: Int = Random.nextInt(6) + 1

for (n <- continually(rollTheDice)) {
  println(s"the dice rolled $n")
}
```

You can see it in action and play around with it [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/d3jdPupkTGC2rVFAUFcVcQ).

Comment: As of 2.13, Stream is deprecated. But the same method does exist in LazyList(import scala.collection.immutable.LazyList.continually)

Answer (score 8):

You can do it recursively

```
@tailrec
def loop(): Nothing = {
 if (condition) {
  // Do something
  } else {
  Thread.sleep(interval);
  }
  loop()
 }
```

Comment: I think [`Nothing`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Nothing.html) would be the more appropriate type. [`Unit`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Unit.html) is the type for something that returns no value. `Nothing` is the type for something that never returns.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Why Nothing is "never returns" ? my understanding is that it is just a bottom type

Comment: A bottom type *is* a type that has no value. (As opposed to a unit type that has a single unique value.)

Comment: Or throws exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

I guess infinite tail recursion:

```
  @tailrec
  def loop(): Nothing = {
     if (condition) {
       // Do something
     } else {
       Thread.sleep(interval);
     }
     loop()
  }
```

Comment: I think [`Nothing`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Nothing.html) would be the more appropriate type. [`Unit`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Unit.html) is the type for something that returns no value. `Nothing` is the type for something that never returns.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Stefano's great answer, in case someone is looking to a use-case like mine:

I was working on tasks from Kafka Streams course and needed to create an infinite stream of mock events to Kafka with some fields being completely random(amounts), but others rotated within a specific list(names).

The same approach with `continually` can be used passing a method(via ETA expansion) to it and traversing the bounded variable afterwards:

```
  for {record <- continually(newRandomTransaction _)
       name <- List("John", "Stephane", "Alice")} {
    producer.send(record(name))
  }
```

where the signature of `newRandomTransaction` is as follows:

```
  def newRandomTransaction(name: String): ProducerRecord[String, String] = {
   ...
  }
```